# what is the best technique to search text for list of word

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i have table contain two column id and word .

word column may contain one word or two or three ex ( computer , computer software , computer software computer )

i want search the text if it contain any word in that table .

thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- change the key word list into a table
- JOIN with LIKE

Optionally:

- COUNT should match number of search terms
- COUNT can also be used for ranking

Better still for larger tables

- or use full text search

Like this

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    Mytable M
    JOIN
    SearchTable S On M.Word LIKE '%' + S.SearchWord + '%'
```

Comment: hello gbn can s be parameter ?

Comment: S is an Alias for SearchTable

Answer (score 1):

If it is small amount of text, you can use "like" with "%" e.g `"select * from tableX where word like '%computer%'"`